# casting long to (void *) to pass

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

Reading through the pthread [tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Management) from LLNL I hit the following example code

```
/******************************************************************************
* FILE: hello.c
* DESCRIPTION:
*   A "hello world" Pthreads program.  Demonstrates thread creation and
*   termination.
* AUTHOR: Blaise Barney
* LAST REVISED: 08/09/11
******************************************************************************/
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++){
     printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
     if (rc){
       printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
       exit(-1);
       }
     }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I can see *why* the `long` is cast through `void *` (as if it's not and you pass a pointer to `t` the numbers printed out by the threads are garbled), my question is should this be considered kosher and always work?  Or is this a quick hack to get the simplest possible example of threading working?  Is this a standard C thing?

Comment: It's definitely a hack. Casting an integer to a pointer and back is UB.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII it's not undefined for `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` :-)

Comment: It's not UB, it's implementation-defined. A subtle difference but an important one.

Comment: C11 6.3.2.3 `An integer may be converted to any pointer type.` /--/ `...the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.` In practice, it is quite safe to rely on this implementation-defined behavior: a long is most likely large enough to hold the address and I can't think of any platform where it leads to a trap representation. Alignment is only an issue if you try to access memory through the pointer.

Comment: I agree with Lundin. This is an issue where all real-world compilers share the same implementation-defined behavior, and where there are major costs (an extra synchronization step) to pass the data to the new thread in any other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not *strictly* kosher in terms of the ISO C standard since there's no guarantee that a pointer is wide enough to hold a long.

A kosher solution would be to pass a *pointer* to the long, either with one unique long per thread (such as one in an array) or having inter-thread communication (such as condition variables) between the creator thread and created thread so that the latter can make a copy before the former is allowed to change it for the next thread creation.

However, the fact that it's not strictly kosher doesn't mean it won't work in a specific implementation. Provided you can guarantee the the cast between `void*` and `long` won't lose any information, it will probably work fine.

From C11 `6.3.2.3 Pointers` (though it's largely unchanged from C99):

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

Comment: Maybe he should use `intptr_t` if he's using C99. It should be defined :-)

Comment: That is what I thought, thanks.  The next section of the tutorial goes through doing the same thing with an array of longs.

Comment: @veer: The standard requires that all pointers be representable in `intptr_t`, not the other way around. And since OP's problem is having a value of type `long` to pass to the new thread, changing the type is probably not feasible in general, although it would be fine for this particular example where the values are all tiny...

Answer (score 0):

It's correct for 32 bit systems only, in case of 64 bits system the size of long is 32 bits but size of void* is 64 bits long.

Comment: The size of `long` is whatever the implementation decides to make it. It can be 32, it can be 64. It can be 128 for all the standards care.

Comment: @Chris is right. ISO sets a minimum _range_ for types which effectively defines the minimum width. But an implementation is free to provide 32-bit pointers and forty-seven-bazillion-bit integers, and the size of the types may or may not be related to the underlying bittedness of the system.

Comment: In practice, no 64-bit implementation has not yet been so stupid that they made long 64 bits though (or...?). The norm is to use long long for 64-bits.

Comment: @Lundin: All 64-bit implementations except Windows have 64-bit long. It's called the LP64 model and it's a universal standard on all unix-like systems.

Comment: @R.. Brilliant... Well, let us hope they upgrade to C99/C11 at some point then.

Comment: Everybody except Windows and various embedded-only C implementations also upgraded to C99 a decade ago... and most of them are close to having C11 support now too.

Comment: Guys, my comment is about code from pthread tutorial. I don't think that this code some how related to the windows or other compiler than gcc. In 32 bit linux kernel, even in kernel mode programming the length of long is equal to length of pointer.